# Verb for getting something (e.g. information) by cunning and/or perseverance

Tags: single-word-requests

I need some information from person A. Person A is not willing to give it to me. So instead of asking directly I keep asking secondary questions hoping that he may say something that might (partially) hint me the information I need. I may even ask other people. Or keep asking so many times that person A would have had it and just told me because he can't stand my questions any more.

It's like extorting, but without using threats or violence, but cunning and perseverance. What word am I looking for?

> Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and finally `<???>` the information from him.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Finagle

I think the word **finagle** has all of the connotations you are looking for.

> Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I
>   persevered and finally **finagled** the information out of him.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finagle) defines finagle as follows:

> **finagle** - intransitive verb
>
> 1 : to obtain by indirect or involved means "finagle a ride home"
>
> 2 : to obtain by trickery "He finagled his way into the concert."
>
> 3 : to use devious or dishonest methods to achieve one's ends "A con
>   man finagled my neighbor out of $400."

Some [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/finagle) for finagle: deceive, manipulate, scheme, swindle, trick

[1] - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finagle

[2] - https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/finagle

Comment: I like that one.

Comment: Doesn't finagle have a connotation similar to haggle?

Comment: The connotation for me was always one of subtle manipulation more so than the negotiation implied by **haggling.**

Answer (score 19):

It's slightly informal, but per Macmillan Dictionary...

> [**ferret out**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ferret-out)
>    *to discover information by searching for it in a determined way*

(A metaphoric reference to using ferrets to catch small game such as rabbits, which would obviously ***hide*** to avoid being detected. The point being that the hunter's search is ***wilfully*** obstructed.)

---

It's often used in contexts where one or more people already have the required information, but ***don't want to reveal it*** - a TV interviewer trying to get a politician to admit potentially damaging facts, for example (see an estimated 13,300 results for [***ferret out the truth***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ferret+out+the+truth%22) in Google Books).

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Thank you, FumbleFingers

Comment: No reference of  **cunning**???

Comment: @Looper: Well, I'd say "about 333 results" in Google Books for [***cunning as a ferret***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cunning+as+a+ferret%22) implies a pretty strong ***allusion*** to cunningly finding something deeply hidden.

Comment: That is kind of an indirect reference. All the dictionaries merriam, oxford etc. supports "assiduous", not cunning, whiling digging information. Anyways, it is far better than any answer here.

Comment: One more thing, OP is looking for either/or, so your answer is good :)

Comment: @Looper: I'd say that *by definition*, such figurative use of ***ferret*** is an "indirect reference" anyway. I can't help it if not everyone knows all the standard metaphoric associations of real-world ferrets.

Comment: Actually [cough] *ferreting out* refers to an old method of rabbit hunting, … totally unrelated to the *cunning* part. And most of those book results don't actually have the whole phrase in, sorry. The phrase itself gets **17** results under "all", most of which are copies of the same *Harry Potter* fanfic :'(

Comment: … you may be thinking of *cunning like a fox*. I up-voted, lest you think I'm criticising the answer itself :)

Answer (score 18):

If your methods were charm, or flattery, you might be said to have [wheedled](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wheedle) the information out of him.

Answer (score 14):

or [wangle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wangle?s=t)

> verb (used with object), wan·gled, wan·gling.
>
> to bring about, accomplish, or obtain by scheming or underhand methods: to wangle an invitation.

I finally [wangled](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/wangle) the information out of him.

In the [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/wangle?s=t) entry you'll find *extricate, wiggle wriggle*.
If you prefer sneaky charm, you could also use *coax, lure, entice, inveigle, wheedle*.

Comment: The definition Google gives me is "(v.) obtain (something that is desired) by persuading others to comply or by manipulating events" which is even closer to what OP is asking for.

Comment: Of very similar meaning would be **Winkle**, referring to the practice of using a pin or needle to remove [Winkles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_periwinkle) from their shells to eat.

Comment: @BallpointBen kind of. You wouldn't *wangle* the *information*, you'd wangle a *confession*... it doesn't really feel comfortable.

Answer (score 12):

[**Cajole**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cajole) (verb)

> to persuade with flattery or gentle urging especially in the face of reluctance: coax

*Merriam-Webster*

or [**Coax**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coax) (verb)

> to manipulate with great perseverance and usually with considerable effort toward a desired state or activity

*Merriam-Webster*

Both of these verbs describe actions to encourage a desired outcome in the face of reluctance or defiance. While "cajole" usually relates to the idiomatic "buttering someone up" to achieve agreement, "coax" isn't always as congenial and could be related to the idiom "wearing someone down," depending on context.

Cajole may be a better fit if the "cunning" behavior could relate to flattery instead of confrontation or subversion.

**"Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and coaxed/cajoled the information from him."**

Comment: Coax is a word you use to describe dealing with stubborn animals and small children! Either works (have a vote!)

Comment: I was going to provide "coaxed" in a new answer but you've clearly beat me to it. This should definitely be the accepted answer since the definition lines up almost perfectly with OP's.

Comment: I don't think either of these fit because OP does not describe getting information through flattery but rather by other deceitful or misdirected methods.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with a very simple and basic expression like [**to get something out of someone**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+(something)+out+of+(someone))? Here's how the Free Dictionary defines it:

> To evoke, illicit, obtain, or wrest something from someone.

Your example:

> Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and finally **got that information out of** him.

Answer (score 5):

You could say you [glean](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/glean?s=t)ed the information

> to gather slowly and laboriously, bit by bit.

[glean](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glean)

> Obtain (information) from various sources, often with difficulty.
>
> ‘Most of her war information is gleaned from her twice-weekly phone chats with her husband.’

ODO defines it as obtaining information from various sources, but has some examples from single sources

Alternatively

You could say you [fish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fish)ed the information out

> Try subtly or deviously to elicit a response or some information from someone.
>
> - ‘Did he really know, or was he fishing for information?’

Note that [fish](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fishing) is used informally

> to seek to obtain something indirectly or by artifice
>
> - to fish for compliments; to fish for information.

Comment: **deviously** suggests malicious intent, not cunning and perseverance.

Comment: OP is not asking about fishing. Fishing is gaining information for wrong purpose. You can fish someone's credit card details.

Comment: @Looper Wouldn't that be **Phish**?

Comment: glean is gaining information laboriously, not cunning and perseverance.

Comment: Although not perfect, I don't understand the downvotes without the "correct" alternatives. Thank you, bookmanu.

Comment: I don't either. I've put you in neutral territory.

Comment: @bookmanu read the [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462374/verb-for-getting-something-e-g-information-by-cunning-and-or-perseverance#comment1115427_462375)

Comment: @Looper [phishing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phishing) please elucidate.

Comment: @Looper Kindly see first definition for [laborious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/laborious)

Comment: @bookmanu FumbleFingers  answer is perfect and looks exactly to OP's requirement. Also, I know the meaning of glen. It does not mean getting information cunningly.

Comment: @Looper Kindly see definition 6 for [subtle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/subtly?s=t)

Comment: @Looper  "The only thing I know is that I know nothing" - Plato on Socrates

Comment: @Looper "laboriously" pretty much involves perseverance by definition.

Comment: Anyway. *Glean* can certainly involve cunning, artifice, or subterfuge; but it's not inherent to the meaning of the word (which means, "pick up" or "collect").

Comment: +1 Fish and (especially) Glean are both good answers.  Both words - and this question - refer to attempting to gain something, within the subtext of that gain being difficult and not guaranteed.  Overcoming this difficulty involves cunning.  I do not understand why this answer isn't more highly voted.  Google's [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=glean): *obtain (information) from various sources, often with difficulty*, is pretty much OP's first paragraph distilled.

Answer (score 5):

**inveigle** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/98950?redirectedFrom=inveigle#eid)

> †1. trans. To blind in mind or judgement; to beguile, deceive, cajole.

As in:

Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and finally **inveigled** the information from him.

Comment: [silent scream] you *inveigle* the person, not the information! :) but it's a **great** word for the situation. Typical use (as shown by Merriam-Webster's examples) is *[person] inveigled [their] way into [something]* or *[person] was inveigled into …*.

Comment: @Will Crawford. But you could also [inveigle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inveigle?s=t) a theatre pass from someone (at least in American English).

Comment: Perhaps there ought to be an American-English SE? ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Weaseled**

> verb
>   past tense: weaseled; past participle: weaseled
>
> ```
> achieve something by use of cunning or deceit.
> "she suspects me of trying to weasel my way into his affections"
> ```

While it can also mean "go get out of in a cunning way", and is often applied to movement, it generally connotes any action that is cunning or surreptitious.

Answer (score 4):

**Wrestled** [from/out]

Using this in a way that the connotation does more of the description than the definition alone. This word allows you to infer the definition of **coerce** without the implications of it's definition and the level of force in its connotation.

> 1. take part in a fight, either as a sport or in earnest, that involves grappling with one's opponent and trying to throw or force
>      them to the ground. "as the policeman wrestled with the gunman a shot
>      rang out"
>
>    force (someone) into a particular position by grappling with them or trying to throw to the ground.
>      "the security guards wrestled them to the ground"
>      move or manipulate (something) in a specified way with difficulty and some physical effort.
>      "she wrestled the keys out of the ignition"
> 2. struggle with a difficulty or problem. "for over a year David wrestled with a guilty conscience"

**Wrangled**, a synonym would be another good option.

Answer (score 3):

Consider "squeeze out"

> Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and finally **squeezed** the information **out of** him.

[Squeeze out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squeeze+out)

> v.
>   1. To extract something by or as if by applying pressure: *I cut open a lemon and squeezed out the juice. The detective squeezed a confession out of the suspect*.

[Squeeze out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squeeze+out)

> squeeze out - obtain with difficulty;

Answer (score 2):

> Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and finally _____ the information from him

Any of the following words would fit the context and I think the intent.

- Dragged - Implying that some effort was required.
- Extracted - Implies use of tools and/or technique (allusions of torture here!)
- Extricated - The information was stuck in some way, perhaps the person has trouble expressing it or had to be lead through the process in order to remember the important details.
- Evinced - Revealed the truth. Perhaps to people around you while interrogating.
- Winkled - similar to extracted, implies technical difficulty in bypassing the person's defences.

Comment: *Dragged … out of* and *extracted* are perfect, but please, *evinced* means *demonstrated*, halfway between *showed* and *evidenced* (or *as evidenced by*).

Comment: In context of the sentence I'd say Evinced works, if a bit of an odd choice. It holds connotations that the speaker has gotten the other person to reveal the information specifically to convince a third party. For example a courtroom interrogation to draw information from a witness. It's a bit of a shaky one, I really only included it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

verb **Badger**

If you badger someone, you repeatedly tell them to do something or repeatedly ask them questions.
She badgered her doctor time and again, pleading with him to do something. [VERB noun]
They kept phoning and writing, badgering me to go back. [VERB noun to-infinitive]
I had foolishly allowed myself to be badgered into volunteering . [VERB noun + into]
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/badger

Comment: Badgering definitely works for the second case in the question, where you annoy someone until they give up.

Answer (score 0):

**["Dig up"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52553?rskey=5Mi4GE&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid)** can work here:

> 1. trans. To take or get out of the ground, etc., by digging or excavating; to exhume, disinter, unearth. **Also fig. to obtain, find, search out**

"Although he refused to tell me where he got the money from, I persevered and finally dug up the information."